# Im trying to add the prices of various items together and display the sum of the costs in Python

Tags: list, append

I am trying to append each itemCost to a list of item itemList
and display the sum before determining if the customer receives free shipping but when I run my debugger the values are not being retained. I tried moving the order around in the while loop but to no avail.

```
[my code][1]
```

Answer (score 0):

Initialize the lists before the while loop or they will be set to zero every iteration of an itemCost being appended.